# do i need aria-checked on an actual checkbox

Tags: html, accessibility, accessible

I've seen a lot of examples of custom built checkboxes using the 'aria-checked' attribute, but do you need to put one when you've got an input type=checkbox?  Or will it be accessible to screen readers natively?

Comment: In short, no. It is redundant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The aria attributes are for when you're not using native html elements.  A native checkbox does not need aria-checked.  If you have a custom checkbox, such as `<span role='checkbox' aria-checked='true'>`, then you do need aria-checked (and other attributes as well).